# How to add delay before autoplay music starts in master page with flash music player

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I want to add some seconds of delay when I visit to every page in my website I am using autoplay on it.
Is there any parameter that can be used with flashvars so that I could add some seconds of delay before music starts because default m`enter code here`usic starts for 1 or 2 sec everytime I visit new page.

<<>>`

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" data="player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="65" height="20">
<param name="movie" value="player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=dummy.mp3&amp;width=65&amp;loop=0&amp;autoplay=1&  amp;volume=60&amp;showvolume=1&amp;showslider=0&amp;showloading=always&amp;buttonwidth=30&amp;volumeheight=8&amp;" />
</object>
```

<<>>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var mp3snd = "/JSRDS/Content/mp3s/PPK_Resurection.mp3";
if ((window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("root/") + 6) ==         window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().length) {mp3snd = "PPK_Resurection.mp3";
}
else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page1.aspx') != -1) {
 mp3snd = "PPK_Resurection.mp3";
}
else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page2.aspx') != -1) {
mp3snd = "GottaWearShades_Intellect.mp3";
}
else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page3.aspx') != -1) {
mp3snd = "MissionImpossible_Rhodium.mp3";
}
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page4.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "Opportunities_Projects.mp3";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page5.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page6.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "HawaiiFiveO_Media.mp3";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page7.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "SayYouSayMe_Photos.mp3";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page8.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "TheLionSleepsTonight_Shihara.mp3";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page9.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "ItsMyLife192vbr_History.mp3";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page10.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page11.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "";
        }
        else if (window.top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('page12.aspx') != -1) {
            mp3snd = "";
        }

        $(".volumeControl").html($(".volumeControl").html().replace("dummy.mp3", mp3snd));
    });
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the swf (ie have fla) then just use [setTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29).

The logic can then be controlled by passing a parameter in flashvars.

```
stop();

setTimeout( playMovie, 1000 )

function playMovie() {

     play();
}
```

Else in JS, you could delay injecting the file onto the page with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) & [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

```
setTimeout (injectSWF , 1000);

function injectSWF() { 

     swfobject.embedSWF("myMovie.swf", "ofc", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0"); 
}
```

Comment: setTimeOut is deprecated and the Timer class would be a better example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find any official statement that AS3 setTimeout() depreciated...  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/deprecated.html. But you are right Timer class would be a better choice.